# Collectd : Could not find plugin "rrdtool" in /opt/collectd/lib/collectd

Tags: collectd

This is first time I am working with collectd.

I have performed the following steps :

1. Downloaded https://collectd.org/files/collectd-5.5.2.tar.gz
2. Extracted the tar.
3. executed `configure`
4. executed `make all install`
5. changed the collectd.conf in `/opt/collectd/etc/collectd.conf`
6. uncommented the necessary plugin and made changes to file paths.

I have used the following [link](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/First_steps).

I am getting the above error when I try to run collectd.
However when I use csv plugin it works correctly.

As much as I understood rrdtool is necessary in order to visualize data.
I need rrdtool so that I can visualize my data.

Is there any other alternative to rrdtool to view data on my browser, or any other tool or plugin using which I can visualize my csv data.

This is what I have figured out after running configure:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the same output you have to find the missign lib.

Dependencies:

```
collectd(x86-64) = 5.6.0-1.sdl7
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libdl.so.2()(64bit)
librrd_th.so.4()(64bit)
rtld(GNU_HASH)
```